# How can I delete a vercel team?

Tags: vercel

I have accidentally created Vercel team. I don't see any option in the dashboard to delete the created team. Is this a design flaw or they don't have any delete option!

Maybe I am missing something, can someone please point this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your team.
2. Go to settings.
3. Scroll all the way down and check the "delete" button.

[image]